# Nginx does not filter the request header contains

Tags: nginx, request-headers

For example, if you set up a custom request header 'world.peace', which is filtered by Nginx when sent to the server

Comment: How to make Nginx not filter request headers containing a dot

Comment: What config you trying? add code to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default nginx ignore the headers containing underscores and dots. Not to ignore them by nginx use the below property at server level.
ignore_invalid_headers off;

Comment: You can find a link to the NGINX common mistakes here https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#:~:text=Missing%20(disappearing)%20HTTP%20Headers%C2%B6